# Getting data from subpage table to google sheet

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I need the data from the following link:
https://sa.investing.com/equities/saudi-arabia
where the needed data is at the subpage "foundmental"

I used the following:
IMPORTXML("https://sa.investing.com/equities/saudi-arabia","//*[(@id = "marketInnerContent")] | //*[(@id = "filter_fundamental")]")

But it doesn’t work.

Please help, thanks

Comment: The one that you used in your post doesn't seem like an xpath. Try this `=IMPORTXML("https://sa.investing.com/equities/saudi-arabia","//*[@id='filter_fundamental']/text()")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=importhtml(A1,"table",B1)
```

with A1 = `https://sa.investing.com/equities/saudi-arabia` and A2 the number of the table (vary from 1 to 12)
[image]